# error: The argument type 'Stream<List<List<NewsModel>>>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Stream<List<NewsModel>>'

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, flutter-getx

I'm extracting two lists from a single stream function to save money by minimizing reads. How can I bind the stream to individual List fields? I'm using Firebase Firestore and Getx State management

The error I'm getting is
`error: The argument type 'Stream<List<List<NewsModel>>>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Stream<List<NewsModel>>'.`

Code:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:dummy_app/models/NewsModel.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

class FirebaseController extends GetxController {
  @override
  void onInit() {
    newsModelList.bindStream(stream()); //Getting ERROR HERE
    newsModelListYesterday.bindStream(stream()); //Getting ERROR HERE
    super.onInit();
  }

  // Observable list bind to stream
  RxList<NewsModel> newsModelList = <NewsModel>[].obs;

  //
  RxList<NewsModel> newsModelListYesterday = <NewsModel>[].obs;

  // Stream
  Stream<List<List<NewsModel>>> stream() {
    return FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('news')
        .doc("Business")
        .snapshots()
        .map((ds) {
      var mapData = ds.data(); // Extracts map
      /// Extracting today and yesterday field
      final stringToday = mapData!['today'];
      final stringYesterday = mapData!['yesterday'];

      /// Storing Lists in a Var
      List mapListToday = mapData![stringToday];
      List mapListYesterday = mapData![stringYesterday];

      /// Empty model lists to assign val
      List<NewsModel> modelListToday = [];
      List<NewsModel> modelListYesterday = [];

      /// Assigning values to both lists
      mapListToday.forEach((element) {
        modelListToday.add(NewsModel.fromMap(element));
      });

      mapListYesterday.forEach((element) {
        modelListYesterday.add(NewsModel.fromMap(element));
      });
      return [modelListToday, modelListYesterday];
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: and why not to create two streams: `Stream<List<NewsModel>> todayDataStream` and `Stream<List<NewsModel>> yesterdayDataStream`? why do you want to pack both lists by `return [modelListToday, modelListYesterday]`?

Comment: I'm trying to minimize the firebase Bill. If I make two functions the same document is been read twice. The Bill is double. Firebase charges every document read. That's the reason. @pskink

Comment: i mean read the firebase document once but create two separate data streams: https://dart.dev/articles/libraries/creating-streams